# NSWindow Full size content view and launching popover causes error

Tags: macos, swift, nswindow, nspopover

After seeing this error in the console when clicking a button to show a popover :

```
unlockFocus called too many times. Called on <NSButton: 0x6180001404d0>
```

I made a copy of my app and stripped it to the bone, before finally finding the issue.
I can replicate this without fail in a new project.

**Can I ask if anyone knows why this is the case, and knows of a workaround, I show the recipe for replicating this error in a new project below..?**

Create new document based project.
Add a push button, a custom view, and the necessary to show the custom view in a popover view :

```
class Document: NSDocument {

    @IBOutlet var thebutton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet var popver: NSPopover!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // Add your subclass-specific initialization here.
    }

    @IBAction func thebuttonclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        var theview = thebutton
        var thebounds = thebutton.bounds
        popver.showRelativeToRect(thebounds, ofView: theview, preferredEdge: NSMinXEdge)
    }
```

Now this is what causes the issue...set the window in IB to "Show full size content"

[image: IB Setting for window]

Run the app the console error is seen when opening the popover by clicking the button :

```
unlockFocus called too many times. Called on <NSButton: 0x6180001404d0>
```

While the popover works at all times, not selecting "Full size content view" for the window in IB results in the error never being seen.

Answer (score 3):

So with the helpful input from a peer. I found a workaround to what appears to be a bug in the OS.

Instead of calling the popover as normal. like :

```
@IBAction func thebuttonclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    var theview = thebutton
    var thebounds = thebutton.bounds
    popver.showRelativeToRect(thebounds, ofView: theview, preferredEdge: NSMinXEdge)
}
```

I must dispatch_async to a launch popover function like this :

```
@IBAction func thebuttonclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.launchmypopover()
    }
}


func launchmypopover(){
    var theview = thebutton
    var thebounds = thebutton.bounds
    popver.showRelativeToRect(thebounds, ofView: theview, preferredEdge: NSMinXEdge)
}
```

I filed a radar regarding this issue. Until the fix is issued, I must use this method.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for sharing this insight.